# PowerBI шлюз на ubuntu

Tags: mysql, docker, администрирование, powerbi

У меня есть `MySQL` база данных на сервере на `ubuntu 20.04`, и она подключена к `PowerBI`. При публикации для обновления данных `PowerBI` требует обязательно шлюз, так как напрямую не может подключится к `MySQL`, это как я понял никак не убрать. Вопрос встал о том, можно ли шлюз `Microsoft Gateway` поставить, может хитрым путем, на этот же сервер на `ubuntu 20.04`, или же обязательно нужен еще один сервак на `Windows`, чтобы там запустить шлюз? Официального дистрибутива я не нашел. Возможно есть какой-то обходной вариант через `Docker`?

Вот официальная страница шлюза:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/ru-ru/gateway/

Comment: Ну поисковики говорят или про Азур или про виртуалку+винду. Новости скорее плохие.

Comment: Я тоже только такое нашел, капец( Имеешь ввиду виртуалку с виндой ставить на Linux? А если доступ только по SSH?

Comment: Доступ куда? На линукс тока по ssh? Ну если есть прям полный доступ, то KVM/Qemu - и winserver/win10 к твоим услугам. Готовишь образ на виртуалке на дектопе, настраиваешь rdp/vnc/winrm и переливаешь на безгуёвый сервак. Либо смотришь в альтернативы powerbi, которые есть на линукс.